# ggmap mapdist function repeating calculation for certain O-D pairs

Tags: r, google-maps-api-3, ggmap

I want to find driving distance and time using the mapdist function in ggmap. The function works well for most Origin Destination pairs given in form of Lat/Long. However, for some O-Ds, the output is repeated.

In the given example, repetition occurs for the 8th and 12th O-D pair. As a result, the output has 14 rows of data although the input had 12 rows only.

Any suggestions?

```
O <- c("37.8405983 -122.2544365",
       "37.7589152 -122.4062322",
       "37.7517621 -122.4062364",
       "37.9659228 -122.505765",
       "37.6969336 -121.8650777",
       "37.9457334 -122.3152847",
       "38.1237134 -122.23956",
       "37.8911093 -122.2813663",
       "37.9067555 -122.0145836",
       "38.0673887 -122.2185562",
       "37.7807761 -122.2102385",
       "37.8911093 -122.2813663")

D <- c("37.8454493 -122.2833803",
       "37.831217 -122.2719625",
       "37.831217 -122.2719625",
       "37.831217 -122.2719625",
       "37.831217 -122.2719625",
       "37.831217 -122.2719625",
       "37.831217 -122.2719625",
       "37.831217 -122.2719625",
       "37.831217 -122.2719625",
       "37.831217 -122.2719625",
       "37.831217 -122.2719625",
       "37.831217 -122.2719625")

DF <- cbind(O, D); DF <- as.data.frame(DF)

GMAPDist <- mapdist(from = O, to = D, mode = "driving",output = "simple")
```

However, if I call the function just for the one O-D pair, then the output is as expected. See below:

```
mapdist(from = c("37.9067555 -122.0145836"), to = c("37.831217 -122.2719625"), mode = "driving",
+ output = "simple")
```

Comment: `GMAPDist[!duplicated(GMAPDist),]` perhaps? Otherwise, this should prbly be [an issue](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues) filed with the maintainer.

Comment: Does my answer solve you problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using a Loop. Note that I have changed the name of the input variables.

**Input Data**

```
from <- c("37.8405983 -122.2544365",
          "37.7589152 -122.4062322",
          "37.7517621 -122.4062364",
          "37.9659228 -122.505765",
          "37.6969336 -121.8650777",
          "37.9457334 -122.3152847",
          "38.1237134 -122.23956",
          "37.8911093 -122.2813663",
          "37.9067555 -122.0145836",
          "38.0673887 -122.2185562",
          "37.7807761 -122.2102385",
          "37.8911093 -122.2813663")

to <- c("37.8454493 -122.2833803",
        "37.831217 -122.2719625",
        "37.831217 -122.2719625",
        "37.831217 -122.2719625",
        "37.831217 -122.2719625",
        "37.831217 -122.2719625",
        "37.831217 -122.2719625",
        "37.831217 -122.2719625",
        "37.831217 -122.2719625",
        "37.831217 -122.2719625",
        "37.831217 -122.2719625",
        "37.831217 -122.2719625")

DF <- cbind(from, to); DF <- as.data.frame(DF) # create data frame
DF$from <- as.character(DF$from) # mapdist demands input to be character type
DF$to <- as.character(DF$to)     # mapdist demands input to be character type
remove (from, to) #remove input to avoid confusion

DF$row.number <- 1:nrow(DF)      #create an index number for each row
```

**Loop - not commented**

```
for (i in DF$row.number){
    orig <- DF[i,c('from')]
    dest <- DF[i,c('to')]
    a <- mapdist(from = orig, to = dest, mode = "driving",output = "simple")
    a$row.number <- i
    DF$minutes[match(a$row.number, DF$row.number)] <- a$minutes
    DF$hours[match(a$row.number, DF$row.number)] <- a$hours
    DF$km[match(a$row.number, DF$row.number)] <- a$km
    }
```

**Loop - with comments**

```
for (i in DF$row.number){
    orig <- DF[i,c('from')] # get origin from DF in the position line 'i', column 'from'
    dest <- DF[i,c('to')]   # get origin from DF in the position line 'i', column 'to'
    a <- mapdist(from = orig, to = dest, mode = "driving",output = "simple") # create temp. df 'a' with the output from mapdist
    a$row.number <- i # include in temp. df 'a' the index number of the row from DF
     DF$minutes[match(a$row.number, DF$row.number)] <- a$minutes # use the index number as a matching key to input/update the value of the variable 'minutes'
    DF$hours[match(a$row.number, DF$row.number)] <- a$hours # ibdem DF$km[match(a$row.number, DF$row.number)] <- a$km #ibdem
    DF$miles[match(a$row.number, DF$row.number)] <- a$miles # ibdem
    }
```

ps.1 - Note that your code is not reading O and D from the data frame

ps.2 - I believe there is a simpler and more efficient way to solve this problem by combining `function` and `lapply`